# Create an ID from Values entered via Form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, cells

being all new to VBA but having to create some sort of DB with Excel i thought that working woth VBA eases the handling by a lot.

so, i made a form with 5 Edits and a button whose function is to copy those entered data to a Worksheet table in the document.

```
.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.oname.Value
.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.ojahr.Value
.Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.oraum.Value
.Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.oregal.Value
.Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.osegment.Value
```

Now what i want to add is a way of creating some kind of "unique" id from 3 of these values and a sequential number.

Best way would be to have it like X-Y-Z-0001
(X,Y,Z, are numerical values)

this is pretty much how i copy the data to the worksheet, and i tried to use

```
.Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.osegment.Value & "-" & Me.osegment.Value & "-" & Me.osegment.Value
```

which unfortunately returns as a date Value (any idea to fix this?)

therefore i changed it to

```
.Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.osegment.Value & "_" & Me.osegment.Value & "_" & Me.osegment.Value
```

works out well, at least as intended (yet the "-" version looks better), the only thing missing is the unique identifier, such as "0001".

So my idea would be to perform somekind of "IF" function that checks for the combination of

```
.Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.osegment.Value & "_" & Me.osegment.Value & "_" & Me.osegment.Value
```

and if this combination didnt exist before, add a _0001.
Otherwise check for existing X_Y_Z_000X values and use +1.

Any kind of help is more than appreciated. :)

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this code:

```
Dim ONameVal As String
Dim OJahrVal As String
Dim OJaumVal As String
Dim ORegalVal As String
Dim OSegmentVal As String

ONameVal = Me.oname.Value
OJahrVal = Me.ojahr.Value
OJaumVal = Me.oraum.Value
ORegalVal = Me.oregal.Value
OSegmentVal = Me.osegment.Value

.Cells(lRow, 3).Value = ONameVal
.Cells(lRow, 4).Value = OJahrVal
.Cells(lRow, 5).Value = OJaumVal
.Cells(lRow, 6).Value = ORegalVal
.Cells(lRow, 7).Value = OSegmentVal

.Cells(lRow, 8).Value = OSegmentVal & "-" & OSegmentVal & "-" & OSegmentVal
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Hey Adhy thanks for your quick Response, 
i tried it out, and it works, sometimes, for some stupid reason Excel still handles it like a date tho, so i changed the seperator from "-" to ".", which works just fine by now. 
The only Thing missing furthermore is some sort of unique identifier. I have to create some Kind of Archive structure, and i want to identify the items by    "room (x), shelf (y) and shelfsegment (z)", for example 2.3.1
Now i try to find a solution to the uniqueness...
to have the result look like 2.3.1-0001 and so on.
I'd appreciate any sort of help <3